# Netlogo - how to pass values of variables from one turtle to another when they are linked

Tags: netlogo

I have a Netlogo model with two kinds of turtles, A and B, and links between them. I would like a variable of turtle A change depending on the value of a variable of turtle B, like this:

```
[ask one-of AB_link-neighbors with [variableA > 0] 
  [set variableA (variableA - variableB)]]
```

And I get error: A breed does not own variable variableB.

Please could anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit more code would be helpful, because it's not clear what context the code block is running in, and I'm not sure what's in `AB_link-neighbors`.  I'm going to guess that `AB_link-neighbors` is one of `B`'s variables, and that it contains `A`s.  I'm also guessing that the outer block in your code is running inside of a `B`, as in:

```
ask B [ask one-of AB_link-neighbors with [variableA > 0] 
        [set variableA (variableA - variableB)]]
```

So `set variableA` refers to the variable of an `A`, and the problem is that

```
    [set variableA (variableA - variableB)]]
```

can only refer to the variables of the asked turtle.  Since that turtle is an `A`, there is no `variableB` available.  A solution is to use `of` with `myself`, which refers to the asking turtle (rather than the asked turtle):

```
ask B [ask one-of AB_link-neighbors with [variableA > 0] 
        [set variableA (variableA - (variableB of myself))]]
```